# How reformat pytorch geometric DataLoader node feature output in batch format?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

How to reformat pytorch geometric torch_geometric.data.DataLoader batch_data's node features into a (batch_size, num_nodes_per_graph, feature_dim) shape ?

The torch_geometric.data.DataLoader produces each batches with batch_data.x (node features) in the shape of (total_num_nodes, feature_dim). But I want to reformat that in model.forward() function in the shape of (batch_size, num_nodes_per_each_sample_graph, feature_dim). Are there any ways to do this ?

For example, reformatting

[1605, 512] --> [64, 40, 512]

Here total num of nodes are 1605. But each samples does not have exactly 40 nodes, so we have to pad them with zeros. But each node features have 512 dimension.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in pytorch geometric documentation. (using torch_geometric.utils.to_dense_batch )
Here is the link to the API - https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/utils.html#torch_geometric.utils.to_dense_batch